# Issue validating user credentials in custom authentication form

Tags: c#, authentication

I have problem with my login system here.

I can go to next form when I input the valid username and password.

And when I input wrong username and correct password, still I can go to next form.

And correct username and wrong password I can still go to next form.

What is the correct code for not letting go to next from if my username or password is wrong?

Here's my code.

```
private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
    if (tbUsername.Text == "username")              
    {                 
        AdminMainMenu x = new AdminMainMenu();
        x.Show();
        t.Play();           
        this.Dispose();          
    }         
    else
    {
        SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username! ", "Error");
    }  

    if (tbPassword.Text == "password")
    {
        AdminMainMenu x = new AdminMainMenu();
        x.Show();
        t.Play();
        this.Dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password! ", "Error");
    }   
}
```

Comment: In what environment is this running? There's no evident redirection here. And what the devil is `t`?

Comment: @Grant Thomas. microsoft visual C# 2008. t is for my soundplayer ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only hazard a guess at what you are asking, but if you want the username and password to both be correct before showing the form use this instead

```
if (tbUsername.Text == "username")
{
    if(tbPassword.Text == "password")
    {
        AdminMainMenu x = new AdminMainMenu();
        x.Show();
        t.Play();
        this.Dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong password", "Error");
    }
}
else
{
    if(tbPassword.Text == "password")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong username", "Error");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong username and password", "Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: i want my code if username is wrong, messagebox will tell me that "invalid username" and when password is wrong it will tell me "invalid password"..

Comment: tnx mate.. your code works. hehee tnx a lot..

Comment: hey mate.. i have another question to ask. what about if username and password are wrong? how to add that code to your code? hehehe

Comment: @Stew I have edited to add that in :)

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the password check `if` block inside the successful username `if` block:

```
private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tbUsername.Text == "username")
    {
        if (tbPassword.Text == "password")
        {
            AdminMainMenu x = new AdminMainMenu();
            x.Show();
            t.Play();
            this.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password! ", "Error");
        }    
    }
    else
    {
        SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username! ", "Error");
    }  
}
```

The way you have it the `else` block for the username check is executing when the username is wrong then the code continues to the password check. You need to make sure the form is shown only after checking both username and password.

Alternatively, you can check both individually and `return` from the click event if the username or password is incorrect like so:

```
private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tbUsername.Text != "username")
    {
        SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username! ", "Error");
        return;
    }

    if (tbPassword.Text != "password")
    {
        SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password! ", "Error");
        return;
    } 

    //If we got here in code execution, then both username and password are correct
    AdminMainMenu x = new AdminMainMenu();
    x.Show();
    t.Play();
    this.Dispose();
}
```